# Ant cannot compile with cross-release process

Tags: java, compilation, ant, javac, annotation-processing

I have a ant process to compile a java 1.8 application. Ant is lauched from Eclipse IDE  in Windows running with java 1.17.
If I try to run Ant process using a separate JDK (1.8), different from the workspace one, I got this error:
[image]

I tried to run Ant with the same version of Eclipse (1.17), I had to add these attributes to `<javac>` element:

```
target="8" source="8" release="8"
```

The compilation starts, but it fails with this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.adrianwalker.multilinestring.JavacMultilineProcessor (in unnamed module @0x4778ea49) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x4778ea49
```

The failing class (JavacMultilineProcessor) is a annotation processor class.
(http://www.adrianwalker.org/2011/12/java-multiline-string.html)

Do you have any idea what happened?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with some other attributes to javac element:

```
<javac fork="true" executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\javac" includeantruntime="false" ... />
```